# The answer to $[a,a)$ and $(a,a]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Well I know $[a,a]={a}$ and $(a,a)=\varnothing$ but $[a,a)$ and $(a,a]$ aren't too logical and I think they don't have answers . Am I right?

Comment: Use the definition of intervals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have, by definition of intervals,
$$
x\in [a, b) \iff a \leq x \text{ and } x<b
$$
Now insert $a$ where I have written $b$ to figure out what it says about $[a, a)$. Are there any $x$ which fulfill the above inequalities? That's your answer for $[a, a)$. The answer for $(a, a]$ is found completely analogously.

Comment: Will it be only $a$ as an answer?

Comment: @Abbas If $x\in [a, a)$, which inequalities should $x$ fulfill?

Comment: there are $x$s which fulfill one of them but not the other so there are no $x$s fulfilling both of them at the same time

Comment: @Abbas And in order for a number to be an element of the interval it has to fulfill both at the same time (that's what the "$\text{and}$" means). Therefore ...?

Comment: So there's no answer!Right?

Comment: When you say "no answer", to me that means that it's impossible to tell. Is that what you meant, or did you mean something like "the answer is nothing"?

Comment: Well it's nothing? Empty set?

Comment: @Abbas Of course it is. If no number fulfills both inequalities at the same time, then the set of numbers which fulfill both at the same time is the empty set.

Comment: Thank you for answering !

Answer (score 2):

Clearly,

$$\{x\in\mathbb R:a\le x<a\}=\{x\in\mathbb R:a< x\le a\}=\varnothing.$$

Comment: Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)), \begin{align}[a,b) &=\{x\in \mathbb R \mid a\leq x<b\}\\
(a,b] &= \{x\in\mathbb R \mid a<x\leq b\}\end{align}

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for help!